# Data binding only updates on onfocus/blur

Tags: angularjs

I have this weird, weird issue.

1. I apply `ng-model` to my input
2. I hit `Get IP`
3. I set the controller's property to match the `ng-model`
4. The input should update

This is what SHOULD happen. However, I have a weird issue, where the data binding won't get updated, until I unfocus/blur the input.

https://jsfiddle.net/941d7qat/

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Controller', function() {
    this.ip = "";

    $("#getIP").on("click", () => {
        $.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json", (response) => {
            this.ip = response.ip;
        });
    });
});
```

I've worked with AngularJS for a few months now (although with TypeScript) and I've never experienced this before. I can see

Comment: Might be because the change is not happening in a digest loop. which is the angular version used

Comment: @ArunPJohny How would that digest loop look like? Google has been of no help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues

1. Don't do dom stuff in your controller, angular already provides to ways to add click event and do ajax. So don't mix jQuery and angular code.
2. In your code the scope is not updated in a digest cycle that is why the input value is not getting updated

So

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Controller', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    this.ip = "";

    this.getIP = () => {
      $http.get('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json').success((response) => {
        this.ip = response.ip;
      })
    }

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller as vm">
  <input type="text" ng-model="vm.ip" id="ip" />
  <button id="getIP" ng-click="vm.getIP()">Get IP</button>
  <br />
  <p>TEST: {{vm.ip}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So the problem is, I'm using regular jQuery instead of AngularJS' $http?

Comment: Awesome, so using `$http` automatically updates the values for me?

Comment: @MortenMoulder yes, since it is part of angularjs it knows to start the digest loop - https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: That's very good to know. Thanks a lot! Still quite new to setting this up manually :) Thanks!